# Ruby Rails Path Show All Item by User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, controller, routes

A RoR beginner here. I am trying to implement a page 'My Products' to show all products added by current user. Currently I have set my 'All Products' page as my index root "products#index". My Product has Controller but my User does not not Controller because I am using Devise. I have a few questions which I still couldnt get it right.

Because currently

Product

```
belongs_to :user
```

User

```
has_many :products
```

routes

```
devise_for :users
resources :products
```

rake routes I have

```
new_user_session      GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
        user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                      PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
    user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                      PATCH  /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                      PUT    /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                      DELETE /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
products              GET    /products(.:format)                       products#index
                      POST   /products(.:format)                       products#create
          new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)                   products#new
         edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)              products#edit
              product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                   products#show
                      PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)                   products#update
                      PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                   products#update
                      DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                   products#destroy
```

Currently what I have in mind to achieve this:

Create a UserController to have @user = User.all then because with association I can use @user.product. (I saw some people said that I shouldn't create new controller because of Devise?) However, I tried to test with rails console before doing the implementation.

```
 product = Product.first
 product.user #here I get all details about user

 user = User.first
 user.product #here I get error. Why it works for product to find user but not both ways?
```

Next, this then makes me wonder how do I create configure the route to get path /users/:id/products . Should I use a nested resource?

Next question, I tried to have

```
resources :users do
  resources :products
end

resources :products
```

I typed in rake routes again. I am confused

```
 user_products GET    /users/:user_id/products(.:format)          products#index
 products GET    /products(.:format)                         products#index
```

Question:

1. Can 2 path has the same Controller#Action?
2. user_products_path and products_path are 2 different path where user_products_path represents user's product. and products_path represents all products

Sorry for the long post.I really wish to clarify those things. Thanks a lot if you could help!! :)

Comment: try   
 user.products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> user.product #here I get error. Why it works for product to find user but not both ways?

As `User has_many :products`, you need to use correct association name as:

```
 user.products # it will give you all products of an user
```

> Can 2 path has the same Controller#Action?

In short, YES. You can specify controller and action name explicitly in your `route.rb` like:

```
get 'users/:id/products' => 'products#index', :as => :user_products_path
```

**Note** that in your case, it will be going into `products#index` by default also.

> user_products_path and products_path are 2 different path where user_products_path represents user's product. and products_path represents all products

Correct, it's absolutely fine. As you are using `devise`, you don't need to use `id` parameter coming from the URL i.e. `users/:id/products`. You can get the user directly from `current_user`, which is better in terms of security also. Keep in mind that if you have admin role who can see details of every user then you will need to manage `id` in that case.

Comment: Assuming I decided to create a new page to show 'My Products', what I did just now was: 
1. Under Products Controller, 
def showall
    @products = current_user.products
  end  
2. Created showall.html.erb under Products view
3. route 
resources :products do
    get :showall
  end 

rake routes and I ended up with 
         product_showall GET    /products/:product_id/showall(.:format)   products#showall

How do I get rid of the product_id ?

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, you should upvote and should create new question for the above issue mentioned in your comment. It will save your current ques to get fade out and other users will be able to get benefit from your question. You can add URL of new question here, so that we can help you

Comment: Noted. Thanks for reminding. Another question by regarding how to modify the url pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652146/modify-url-pattern-ruby-rails Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're just starting out, I'll keep this example simple with having easy to read logic. However, there are better ways to configure and optimize this so that you're not relying on `if` statements in your controller.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:user_id]
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @products = @user.products.all
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
  end
end
```

One reason why this is bad practice is that you're relying on the `user_id` param to be valid. If the `user_id` param is not valid, then the second line `@products = @user.products.all` will return `undefined method for Nil class`.

Also, in your views, if you reference `@user` then you will get an error if you're just listing out all products.

Also, there isn't any security being done where anyone can see anyone's products if they know or try to guess the user's `id`.

However, this should work in your instance. You may also want to consider that if the `user_id` is present to then call `current_user.products.all` so that it will only return the current user's products instead of the particular `user_id`'s. However, it is really up to how you're designing the application that will determine the best route to take.

What I'll typically do is if the `/products` route should be for the administrative level, I'll `namespace` it and put the appropriate security around the namespacing so that it does not allow general users to access it, but rather only administrators of the site.