# Modify URL Pattern Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes

I am trying to display a page to show all products by current user. Because of this, I have created a new page showall.html.erb under products view.

I have done the following:

ProductsController

```
def showall
  @products = current_user.products
end
```

routes

```
resources :products do
  get :showall
end
```

I am aware that because of the nested resources the URL Pattern became

```
 /products/:product_id/showall(.:format)
```

How do I actually get rid of the product_id part to achieve /products/showall to have one special page to render all products by the current user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change your route definition as follows:

```
resources :products do
  collection do 
    get :showall
  end
end
```

Check corresponding [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Solved my problem but I am faced with 'Resource not found'.  :( I have this link <li><%= link_to 'My Products', showall_products_path %></li> but Resource not found :( :( :(

Comment: Could you provide more information about the new error? Where does it come from? Is it from controller? If you have stack trace - it would also help.

Comment: Found my problem. Stupid me who put showall in before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] . Thanks for the solutions you gave earlier! Really helpful!!!!